# How do I get out of a blue-text cmd screen after running 'git commit' without a message?

Tags: git

I did a `git add` for a `codeshare10-18.txt` I wanted to push into my own respository. I then did `git commit codeshare10-18.txt`, and since I forgot to add a message, I got a warning with this at the end:

```
"C:/Users/Nicolas/Desktop/workshop/neobis001.github.io/.git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp" already exists!
[O]pen Read-Only, (E)dit anyway, (R)ecover, (D)elete it, (Q)uit, (A)bort:
```

I didn't know what to do, so I pressed `E` because I thought I could add a message that way. I got this colored screen in return:

[image]

I tried typing a message like "Added a txt". The "A" got cut off, and when I tried to press Enter, it just made a newline in cmd to type more stuff. What is this window, and how do I get out of this window without clicking the X button? I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd>, and "exit" plus <kbd>Enter</kbd>, but none of them worked. I know next time I should include a message, but I'd still like to know how to get out of here via a console command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is the vim text editor.

When it opens up, you can to the following:

- Press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter insert mode
- Type in your commit message
- press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to exit insert mode
- press <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to save and exit

Alternatively, for the last step you can type in `:wq`<kbd>ENTER</kbd> (<kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> is just a shortcut to that).

Comment: I tried "ZZ" but I get `E45: 'readonly' option is set (add ! to override)`. I tried "!", but nothing happened. I also tried `wq` then Enter, but I get the same message back. Do you know what to do from here?

Comment: @DragonautX You can save&exit a readonly file using `:wq!<ENTER>` as a last step. But perhaps it's best to just remove the `C:/Users/Nicolas/Desktop/workshop/neobis001.github.io/.git/.COMMIT_EDITMSG.swp` file and then commit the way you usually do.

Comment: Thanks. I'll google more about the vim text editor, didn't know what it was called before.

Comment: @DragonautX: VI and VIM are quite famous for various reasons, one of them is a user not accustomed to VIM getting stuck in it. There's even a joke about using VIM as a secure screen saver, because noone knows how to exit from it..

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Haha nice one. If I ever have to do a lab at my university with git, I'll make sure to tell that to my partner.

Comment: there's also this joke: https://github.com/thepracticaldev/orly-full-res/blob/master/exitingvim-big.png :)